# Nebular ngx admin login authcard work flow?

Tags: angular, nebular

I want to know the workflow for getting user data from JWT token. I have followed the document But I didn't get the user details.

Reference Link: https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/getting-user-token#getting-user-token

Please anyone let me know where I missed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you already have the authentication working and are receiving a valid token in return.  For my case I simply made a `UserService` that subscribes to `onTokenChange()` of `NbAuthService`.  `NbAuthJWTToken` token has a method to get the token payload `getPayload()`.  From there I just publish the token payload to my `Subject` in my `UserService`.  Any component that needs the user data will use the `UserService` and subscribe to the user details.

Something like this....

#### user.model.ts

```js
export class User {
  public id: string;
  public username: string;
  public fullname: string;
  public email: string;
  public roles: string[];

  constructor(obj: any) {
    this.id = obj.nameid
    this.username = obj.unique_name;
    this.fullname = obj.full_name;
    this.email = obj.email;
    this.roles = Array.isArray(obj.role) ? obj.role : [obj.role];
  }
}
```

#### user.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService implements OnDestroy {

  private _tokenChangeSubscription: Subscription;
  private _userDetailsData: User = null;
  private _userDetailsSource: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(this._userDetailsData);

  /**
     You could inject NbTokenService here as well.  Then subscribe to the token
     changes with 
     
     this._tokenService.tokenChange()
       .subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => ...);
   */

  constructor(private _authService: NbAuthService) {
    this._tokenChangeSubscription = this._authService.onTokenChange()
      .subscribe((token: NbAuthJWTToken) => {
        if (token.isValid()) {
          const payload = token.getPayload();
          this._userDetailsData = new User(payload);
          this._userDetailsSource.next(this._userDetailsData);
        }
      });
  }

  getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
    return this._userDetailsSource.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._tokenChangeSubscription)
      this._tokenChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Here I used the `NbAuthService` but you can achieve the same using the `NbTokenService` if you prefer.  Both services have Observables that you can subscribe to to receive the new token when it changes (on authentication, on refresth).

> https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/nbauthservice#nbauthservice
>
> https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/nbtokenservice#nbtokenservice

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide your `auth module` configuration and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/akveo/nebular-seed)  example?